# unable to use MYSQL INSERT INTO in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Actually I'm new to this and having problem with insert into property of mysql.

I created two tables namely questions and answers. user can put up data(for both table) through html form.  because of some unknown mistake, data is not inserting into the answer table, there is no such problem with question table.
Strange thing is that php code of insertion for both tables is almost same excepting variable's name.

singleques_info.php code:

```
<?PHP

 session_start();
 $t=$_GET['p'];
 $ans= "";
 $error_message = "";
 $num_rows = 0;

 function quote_smart($value, $handle)
 {
     if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
         $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
     if (!is_numeric($value)) 
        {
         $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
        }
     return $value;
     }

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
         $ans = $_POST['ans'];
         $ans = htmlspecialchars($ans);
         $uLength = strlen($ans);
         if ($uLength <=100) 
          {
         $error_message = "";
          }
           else 
          {
           $error_message = $error_message . "Username must be between 10 and 20 characters" . "<BR>";
          }


    if ($error_message == "") 
      {
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "techinsight";
        $server = "127.0.0.1";
        $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
        $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

        if ($db_found) 
         {
         echo "connected";
         $ans = quote_smart($ans, $db_handle);
         $SQL = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer= $ans";
         $result = mysql_query($SQL);
         $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
          if ($num_rows > 0)
           {
            echo "Question already taken";
           }
            else
           }                          
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO answers (Aid, answer, date) VALUES ($t, $ans, CURDATE())";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            mysql_close($db_handle);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "1";

            header ("Location:ques_wala_main.php");
            echo "You are done.";
           }

        }
         else 
        {
          $errorMessage = "Database Not Found";
        }

      }
      //<div class="content_mess">
  /*    else
        {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['login'] = "";
           header ("Location: signup.php");
           echo "Please SignIn Before Asking....";
        }
  // </div> */

 }

 ?>
```

html form :

```
 <form id="ans" method="POST" name="ans" action="#">
   <div class="field extra">
    <label>your answer:</label> <br/> <br/> <br/>
    <textarea name="ans" cols="70" rows="6"></textarea>
   </div>
   <br/> <br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: I also noticed that you're connecting to DB **after** `if ($error_message == "")`and accessing `mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle)` before that. Are you connected to DB above that?

Comment: Plus, using `$t=$_GET['p'];` which is a GET method from a POST method. Where is `$t=$_GET['p'];` being populated from?

Comment: actually that GET method is used here to retrieve variable from another page passed through url.

Comment: Is it really necessary to connect to db before that if statement?

Comment: why does it is not working for the answer table ,when php and html code is same for both tables? where questions are easily gets stored in the question table.

Comment: You need to first connect to DB before calling any SQL functions.

Comment: nothing is changed, seems it will not work. i'm unable to seek the mistake that is creating problem.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if that helps.

Comment: okay, an error is just appeared i.e.                        Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: That is both bad and "good" at the same time since we now know what the problem is, as it seems that `mysql_*` functions are no longer available on the server you are on. So now you have to change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and you might have to do a few modifications to the way you're connecting to DB. In `mysqli_*`, the DB connection comes first.

Comment: but why does functions of mysql are not working here.

Comment: Maybe because like I said, the server you are on have upgraded to the newer version of PHP and those old functions are not available now because of it.

Comment: very frustrating, whatever the reason is.  Anyways,thanks for your help. i'll write to you again if it'll not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by OP adding the following to the top of script(s):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Having to find out that the `mysql_*` functions were no longer supported on the server and had to resort to switching to `mysqli_*` functions.

This having conversed with OP through multiple comments.

---

When now using `mysqli_*` functions, (with an extra option):

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

MySQL (error reporting links)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

---

Additional APIs:

[**Use mysqli with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo)

PDO error handling:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered in the comments but I'll expand.

You seem to be puzzled with two aspects. The first is the correct preparation of SQL statements, which you're using here. Each statement consists of two important parts. You specify:

1. columns of the table you want to use:

   INSERT INTO answers (Aid, answer, date)
2. and values you want to use with these columns:

   VALUES ($t, $ans, CURDATE())

The [MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) allows you to leave the column names unencapsulated if there are no spaces (or some other characters) in them, so this part is okay. The values however, depending on the columns types might have to be encapsulated with single or double quotes, e.g. you have to encapsulate values for `VARCHAR`, `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `BLOB` but you shouldn't usually do so for numeric types like `INT` and `DECIMAL` or whenever you're telling the MySQL server to calculate something before it inserts the new record (like `CURDATE()`, `10 + 5` etc.). So assuming your columns are:

```
Aid    - INT
answer - VARCHAR
date   - DATE
```

the correct SQL statement would be (notice the single quotes around `$ans` and lack of quotes around `CURDATE()`):

```
INSERT INTO answers (Aid, answer, date) VALUES ($t, '$ans', CURDATE())
```

The other aspect that seems to confuse you is how [PHP deals with strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). What you're doing is telling the PHP to prepare a line of text (string) and pass it into a MySQL server so that the server would run it and pass the result back to the PHP (e.g. `mysql_insert_id()` is such a result). The thing is PHP from the beginning to the end of this process has no idea what an SQL statement is and how to prepare it. All it knows is "here's a string and I need to put some variables in". So assuming the answer number `32` was `a submitted answer`, these two parts of your code:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer= $ans";
[...]
$SQL = "INSERT INTO answers (Aid, answer, date) VALUES ($t, $ans, CURDATE())";
```

would produce the following correct strings but incorrect SQL statements:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer= a submitted answer
INSERT INTO answers (Aid, answer, date) VALUES (32, a submitted answer, CURDATE())
```

Hopefully the solution is now obvious.

Above said, I'm responding only to pay it forward (all of us had to start somewhere). This coding style is outdated and it's value arguable (even as a means to learn). It never should see a production environment.

EDITED:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
```

The above should be a notice level and probably isn't an issue. If you want to check whether functions are available run the following script:

```
<?php
    $a = array(
        'mysql_connect', 
        'mysql_real_escape_string',
        'mysql_query',
        'mysql_fetch_assoc',
    );

    foreach ($a as $f)
        var_dump(function_exists($f));
```

Comment: Please put into your answer `$ans` must be quoted to `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer= $ans";`